# Remove pseudo-blanks in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Is there a way to make supposedly blank cells truly blank?

I have had a bunch of formulae evaluate to `""`, whereafter I proceeded to copy the results and paste values. Now when I check for blanks using `ISBLANK(A1)` or `IF(A1="",TRUE,FALSE)` I get `FALSE`, unless I select the pseudo-blank cell and press delete first.

There are quite a few of these cells so I tried using F5 (Go To Special) but none of the options (blank, constants, etc.) give the appropriate selection of the pseudo-blank cells.

How do I locate all these pseudo-blank cells in one go and delete them so that I can obtain truly blank cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick VBA routine.
Looks through every *Used* cell. If cell is not empty but the value is a nullstring then clear this cell.

```
Sub clearEmptyValues()
For Each cell In UsedRange
    If Not IsEmpty(cell) And cell.Value = vbNullString Then cell.Formula = vbNullString
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Just out of interest, is there a non-VBA solution?

Comment: Thanks, for those interested, changing cell.Clear to cell.Value = "" will remove cell contents but keep formats intact.

Comment: See my edit. Now it clears only the `formula` and leaves formatting in tact. And your solution does also work. Regarding your first question: I doubt there is a non-VBA solution

Comment: Thank you nixda for your attention to this question. I appreciate it!